# How can I get the data from div already divided

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi everyone I want to extract data from divs using Jquerys.
So I have this 3 div :

```
<div class="wind">Venice,it</div>
<div class="wind">Madrid,es</div>
<div class="wind">Rome,it</div>
```

In my JS file I want to extract: Venice,it  / Madrid,es / Rome,it.

What I did for now is: `var data = $("div.wind").text() .`

Writing this I get the string Venice,itMadrid,esRome,it  but I don't want to this. I want the div splitted already like.

```
var vector= [(Venice,it),(Madrid,es),(Rome,it)]
```

How can I do this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.each()`

```js
$(() => {
  var vector = []
  $(".wind").each(function(){ vector.push($(this).text()) })
  console.log(vector)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wind">Venice,it</div>
<div class="wind">Madrid,es</div>
<div class="wind">Rome,it</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm super new to JS and jQuery, it's my second day :))

Comment: Why not use `map()` instead of `each()`? Then it's a one-liner.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Just keeping it simple for OP to understand

Comment: I'd argue it's better to provide the best solution, not the simplest just so it can be easily understood.

Answer (score 1):

```
const divs = $("div.wind");
const data = divs.toArray().map(d => d.textContent)
```

Comment: By far the best solution here, although you need to add `get()` to the end of the `map()` call

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Why? Where? Array has no `get()` method, and `textContent` is of type `string`. which also has no `get()` method.

Comment: You're right, I misread. I thought you were using the jquery map() function

Answer (score 1):

just use push on the innerHTML

```js
var myArray=[];
var div =document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(let i=0;i<div.length;i++){

myArray.push(div[i].innerHTML);
}
console.log(myArray);
```

```html
<div class="wind">Venice,it</div>
<div class="wind">Madrid,es</div>
<div class="wind">Rome,it</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `.each` to iterate through each `div` selected.  You can then get the `.text()` value for each `div` one by one, and push the value into the `vector` array.

**Demo:**

```js
var vector = [];
$("div.wind").each(function(index, div) {
  var data = $(div).text();
  vector.push(data);
});
console.log(vector);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wind">Venice,it</div>
<div class="wind">Madrid,es</div>
<div class="wind">Rome,it</div>
```